# Objective-C UIButton&viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a newbie who is learning OC.

But now when I set an outlet button as a property of my viewcontroller, in order to add an attribute for it, when I write some methods in `viewDidLoad`, something wrong happened like this:

The only thing I want to do is to set the attributes of the `outLetButton.currentTitle`

And my code is as follows:

There is nothing wrong with my button.

```
(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

/

NSMutableAttributedString * title = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:self.OutletButton.currentTitle] ;

[title setAttributes:@{NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:@3.0,NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[self.OutletButton tintColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])] ;

[self.OutletButton setAttributedTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;

}
```

I used breakout debugging, when I step over `[title setAttributes...]`, it crashed.

***First throw call stack***

0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba0b12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b09ff41 objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba8c024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132

3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b98df78 ***forwarding*** + 1432

4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b98d958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120

5   UITextView                          0x000000010a791106 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 598

6   UIKit                               0x000000010c03146c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235

7   UIKit                               0x000000010c0318b9 -[UIViewController view] + 27

8   UIKit                               0x000000010befc7cf -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122

9   UIKit                               0x000000010befced7 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294

10  UIKit                               0x000000010bf0fe54 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42

11  UIKit                               0x000000010be828b8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4737

12  UIKit                               0x000000010be87aeb -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1720

13  UIKit                               0x000000010c2516f8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 924

14  UIKit                               0x000000010c6274c8 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153

15  UIKit                               0x000000010c2512f1 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 249

16  UIKit                               0x000000010c251b6b -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 696

17  UIKit                               0x000000010cbcfa69 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 262

18  UIKit                               0x000000010cbcf922 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444

19  UIKit                               0x000000010c8ac9c8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221

20  UIKit                               0x000000010caabb06 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100

21  UIKit                               0x000000010c8ac88b -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 231

22  UIKit                               0x000000010c626b25 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392

23  UIKit                               0x000000010be8636a -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 523

24  UIKit                               0x000000010c461605 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 369

25  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110158cc0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 338

26  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001101617b5 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 235

27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f3b733d _dispatch_client_callout + 8

28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f3bc9f3 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592

29  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011018d498 **FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24

30  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011018d14e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 464

31  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011018d6bd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45

32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9ae101 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17

33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba4df71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81

34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b992a19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185

35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b991fff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279

36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b991889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409

37  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110a219c6 GSEventRunModal + 62

38  UIKit                               0x000000010be895d6 UIApplicationMain + 159

39  UITextView                          0x000000010a7914df main + 111

40  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f433d81 start + 1

41  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you are initialising `NSMutableAttributedString` with `NSMutableString` & then changes its attribute..

The code lets you initialise the variable But `NSMutableString` doesn't allow you to add attributes so it crashes..

The code should be like this.. (change allocation class to **NSMutableAttributedString**)

```
NSMutableAttributedString * title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.OutletButton.currentTitle] ;

[title setAttributes:@{NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:@3.0,NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[self.OutletButton tintColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])] ;

[self.OutletButton setAttributedTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
```

Thanks.